# Storing Numerical Data in a Variable through matching in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am a beginner at Perl and want to store some data from a file format into a variable. Specifically, each line of the file has a format like the following:

```
ATOM     575  CB   ASP 2   72   -2.80100  -7.45000  -2.09400 C_3    4 0 -0.28000 0   0
```

I was able to use matching to get the line I wanted (with the code below).

```
if ($line =~ /^ATOM\s+\d+\s+(CB+)\s+$residue_name+\s+\d+\s+$residue_number/)
{

}
```

However, I want to store the three coordinate values as variables or in a hash. Is it possible to use matching to store the coordinate values rather than having to use substring.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough, can you elaborate more?

Comment: wrap the parts you want to have in parentheses... you can then access them after the match in `$1`, `$2` and so on (counting by opening parentheses from left to right). [Further reading on capturing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

Comment: Perhaps you should try `my @items = split ' ', $line`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this instance I would simply `split` each record into an array and verify the identifying fields. The coordinate values can simply be extracted from the array if the line has been found to be relevant.

Like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $residue_name   = 'ASP';
my $residue_number = 72;

while (<DATA>) {
  my @fields = split;
  next unless $fields[0] eq 'ATOM'
      and $fields[2] eq 'CB'
      and $fields[3] eq $residue_name
      and $fields[5] == $residue_number;

  my @coords = @fields[6, 7, 8];
  print "@coords\n";
}


__DATA__
ATOM     575  CB   ASP 2   72   -2.80100  -7.45000  -2.09400 C_3    4 0 -0.28000 0   0
```

**output**

```
-2.80100 -7.45000 -2.09400
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the end of the line which is AFTER the match with $' (see http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html), and split around spaces like in :

```
if ($line =~ /^ATOM\s+\d+\s+(CB+)\s+$residue_name+\s+\d+\s+$residue_number/)
{
$_ = $';
(undef, $x, $y, $z) = split /\s+/;
...
}
```

(undef is necessary, because $_ will start with some spaces, thus the first variable will be empty)

You can also write something like :

```
if ($line =~ /^ATOM\s+\d+\s+(CB+)\s+$residue_name+\s+\d+\s+$residue_number/)
{
$_ = $';
/\s+(-?\d+\.?\d*)\s+(-?\d+\.?\d*)\s+(-?\d+\.?\d*)/;
($x, $y, $z) = ($1, $2, $3);
}
```

In fact, as always in Perl, there are lots of ways to do it...